# Reconstruct meshes of 1, 2 or 3-connected surfaces from sparse point clouds

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d, computational-geometry, point-clouds

I've got some point clouds – *i.e.* collection of 3d coordinates – whose underlying structures that I'd like to reconstruct, even just approximately, are 2D surfaces in the 3D space with either 0 (fig B), 1 (fig A) or 2 holes, or the disjoint union of two or more such structures (fig C).

Each surface is not a closed boundary to a 3D domain (my structures are 2 dimensional). Mathematically speaking, they are genus 0 2-manifolds with 1,2 or 3 boundary components or a disjoint union of such structures.

[image]
↑ *"out" should be actually made of triangles; actual point clouds are not so obviously coming from spheres*

[ As an example, think of the set of points defined as "sampled points on the surface of a mountain range whose distance from a air balloon is between 100 and 150 m". These points represent a surface that can either have 0 holes (the top of the mountain), 1 hole (the flank), 2 holes (a valley which is a basis for 2 mountains) ]

My expected output is a set of edges and triangular faces connecting the existing vertices. I'll use it for rough surface area estimates and for a graphic representation of my dataset. I don't need the resulting surface to be perfect: even topological artifacts (holes that shouldn't be there) can be acceptable if they are limited in number.

My point cloud has some features:

- the density of point is somewhat constant, and if a set is made of non connected surfaces I should be able to tell them apart using a threshold
- sometimes a "strip" of surface can narrow down to a single file of points, or even skip some points (see example C, left component)

I know there cannot be an exact reconstruction algorithm, but maybe there are canonical ways to minimise the total length of the edges, or the total surface area, or the crease angle between neighbouring faces: I'm not sure as I'm not from the computational geometry field.

If that helps, I'll be implementing this in Java, but it's the algorithm I'm interested in. I don't mind if the algorithm relies on parameters as long as it doesn't make assumptions that don't hold in my case.

Thanks!

Comment: If the density is at least close to constant (let's say at most varies by the value of 2 locally), a naive approach of inserting edges between any points that have a distance below a fixed threshold should totally do. Searching those can be done using a kd-tree (or alternative data-structure). If that doesn't suffice you could try adding weights to the distance-function based on local distance.

Answer (score 0):

When density is close to constant, i.e. space between points is similar, two methods are useful for triangulations: "Marching Cubes" and "Ball Pivot"

Comment: I don't see how Marching Cubes can help. But I agree with Ball Pivoting. MeshLab has it implemented. So you could try to run it there to see if the results are satisfactory.

Comment: I didn't know about Ball Pivot, I'll try it and see if it fits my needs. As for Marching Cubes, if I'm not mistaken it requires points on the surface as well as points enclosed by the surface and outside the enclosed volume (like in isosurfaces), which I don't have in my dataset.